# Android Support Libraries

Tags: android, android-support-library

Sorry might be silly question here. First of all i am a bit new to android.There is always confusion in my mind when it comes to **Support Library**. What killing me most is if I have multiple libraries in my dependencies and each use different **Support Library versions**. One use **V4** and other use **"v7"** with different build version. Project it's self use another version. Wouldn't be any conflict or duplicate entries cuz each one has separate versions. :-)

**Edited**

Library A ( v7:22.1.1 )

Library B ( v4:19.1.0 )

Library C ( v4:18.0.0 )

app ( v4:18.0.0 )

As my expectation , there should be conflict but i can run project without any flaw which make me big confusion.

**Edited**

It is said that v7 include v4 so i removed **support library** in all sub modules and put v7 in **app module**. After i had changed ,i've errors and can't even build ..

Would be very appreciate for explanation cuz mostly all beginner might have those confusion

Comment: check android developer resource for more specific details about `Support Library` [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)

Comment: Hi please consider giving some feedback to answers, either upvote or downvotes or inquiry something if still not clear..

Answer (score 1):

Actually v7 includes the v4 support library. There wont be any conflict and duplicate entries between them.

**v4 Support Library**

This library is designed to be used with Android 1.6 (API level 4) and higher. It includes the largest set of APIs compared to the other libraries, including support for application components, user interface features, accessibility, data handling, network connectivity, and programming utilities.

**v7 Support Libraries**

It contains several libraries designed to be used with Android 2.1 (API level 7) and higher. These libraries provide specific feature sets and can be included in your application independently from each other and added extra features.

Answer (score 0):

`v7` include `v4` support library so if you are importing v7 than no need to add v4

You can check in `v7 libs folder it includes v4 library`

Now if you have multiple library(module) project which has some hierarchy than attach library to the main parent library and add that parent library to your sub library project or main project

`Library_A` (Required v4 or v7's some of the classes)

`Library_A1` (Required v4 or v7's some of the classes)

`Main_Porject`(Final one)

*Add Support v7 to Library_A only*

*Add Library_A to Library_A1 as a module*

**No need to add v7 to both Library_A & Library_A1 it can cause conflicts**

*Attach only Library_A1 to Main_Project as a Module.*

And Using multiple v7 library with different version will cause problem.

Comment: why can't add **V7** to **Main_Project** and let **A** and **A1** depend on **Main_Project** .

Comment: hello @Sanny Yes you can BUT if theres no need to v7 library in **A** & **B** . only **Main_Project** should required v7 thn